# Adapt interface to window width

Tags: java, gwt, window, width

I have created a gwt interface (which appears on the browser). How can I make its width "resilient" so as when the browser window re-sizes the width of the interface to fit the window' s width?

Answer (score 0):

This is what happens automatically, if you start with RootLayoutPanel, and then nest [layout panels](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiPanels#LayoutPanels) (LayoutPanel, DockLayoutPanel, ...) until you reach your content that needs to stretch.

Make sure to use [standards mode](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiPanels#Standards) for the HTML page, otherwise it may not work in all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

It should be as easy as **not** using pixels or other fixed-size units.

But you know, GWT doesn't save you from learning HTML and CSS (or even JavaScript)